# Ruby on Rails - Model

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, model

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpqC1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpUdx.png)

I have two tables one of the clients and another of called.
Each ticket is linked to 1 customer.
In the client table, I have the parent client, each with its own ID and I also have child clients, for these, we have the parent client ID defined in the `entities_id` column.

I need to query all calls from parent and child clients, but calls from child clients should be displayed as if they were from the parent client, how can I make this query?

Answer (score 1):

What I've understood is

```
class Client
  has_many :calls
  has_many :child_clients, :class_name => 'Client',
  belongs_to :parent_client, :class_name => 'Client'
end

class Call
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I did not understood this part in your question

> "but calls from child clients should be displayed as if they were from
>   the parent client"

But here could be some interesting request:

- current_client.parent_client.calls
- current_client.child_clients.map(:calls)
- Call.where(client_id: [current_client.parent_client_id, current_client.child_clients.map(&:id)].flatten)

Ps:

Your question is not really clear and could be a lot better:

- You could have inserted your images directly
- You speak about clients but your image shows entities
- You could drop us some model definition instead of tables.